# PC Monitor Did Not Have Signal Yesterday - But Again Today?

Tags: display, hardware-failure, external-display

Yesterday, my pc monitor did say that it does not have any signal, even though my pc was pluged-in as usual. I even tried a different cable and a different source (laptop), but still no picture, not even the menu from the monitor showed up anymore. The pc and laptop were fine, they both worked with the tv as alternative display.

However, a day later, the monitor works again as if nothing happened. Is this only temporary (like with hard disk fails, they slowly build up) and I should consider buying a new monitor (it is 5+ years old and was used daily for at least 12h) or did I miss something and the monitor is just fine?

Is there a way to test monitor health as it is possible with hard drives with CrystalDiskInfo for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to test the health of a monitor, except if such is
available via the monitor's On Screen Display (OSD).

There is one more test to do - try another monitor.

If the other monitor has no such problem, then the old one is
to be replaced.

If it shows the same problem, then the problem is with the computer,
probably having to do with the display adapter.

Comment: Thanks, I did that with the TV display yesterday already. Is there a typical sign that the monitor is really broken? I never had that before in my life, and the strange thing for me was, that the monitor still was able to show the message "no signal detected" - so it wasn't completely out. Or in other words: is it possible that a monitor is broken, but still works sometimes?

Comment: That's certainly possible. It may mean that one component of the monitor is on the blink but the rest is fine. It might be repairable, but a 5 years old monitor may not be worth the investment,

Comment: That makes sense, thanks